# Call a child class method from a parent class object (saving objects with type parent in a vector)

Tags: c++, vector, parent-child

My program has 1 parent class called `Player` and two child classes `Warrior` and `Vampire`. New `Player`s are read from a setting.txt file and the created players are saved in `vector <Players*>` arena. The players are pushed back in the vector : `arena.push_back(new Warrior)`
The type (`Warrior` or `Vampire`) for each player is also read from the setting.txt.
I have a method `Warrior::attack` and a method `Vampire::attack`.

If I add a new `Warrior` into the `vector`, I cannot later access the `Warrior::attack` method. I used virtual but is there another better way? If im creating an object `new Warrior` and pushing back the pointer to it in the vector of Parent class. IS there a way to access child methods without using virtual?

I tried using virtual. I made a virtual method in parent class and made methods with same name in child classes. And depending on which child class i use the function on i get the attack method from that child.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using std::cout, std::endl, std::ifstream,std::string,std::vector,std::ostream;


class Player {
public:
    static size_t baseHitPoints;
    static size_t baseStrength;

protected:
    size_t hitPoints;
    size_t strength;
public:
    //constructor for parent class
    Player(): hitPoints(baseHitPoints), strength(baseStrength) {}
    //check if player is alive
    bool isAlive() const {
        return hitPoints > 0;
    }
    //class is virtual to allow children functions to work
    virtual ~Player() = default;
    //attack another Player p
    void initattacks(Player& other){
        if(this->hitPoints>0 and other.hitPoints >0 and other.hitPoints>this->strength)other.hitPoints= other.hitPoints-this->strength;
        else if(other.hitPoints<=(this->strength))other.hitPoints=0;
    }
    //virtual function to attack. Depending on who is attacking warrior::attack or vampire::attack is picked
    virtual void attacks(Player& other){
        this->initattacks(other);
    }
    //print funtion dependent on child class type
    virtual ostream& print(ostream& output)const{
        output<<"Player DATA";
        return output;
    }
    //virtual and friend dont go together why??
    //operator overloading to make printin easier
    friend ostream& operator <<(ostream& output, const Player& other){
        return other.print(output);
    }

};

//child classs 1
class Warrior : public Player{
public:
//constructor
    Warrior():Player(){
        this->Player::hitPoints=Player::hitPoints+bonus;
        this->Player::strength=Player::strength+bonus;
    }
    //static need to be initialized seperate like:: Warrior::bonus =...
    //initialized before making class(i think/ask)
    static size_t bonus;
    void attacks(Player& other)override{
        this->Player::initattacks(other);
    }
    //virtual and overriding the print funtion. Is there easier way??
    ostream& print(ostream& output)const override{
        cout<<"Warrior ("<<Player::hitPoints<<"HP, "<<strength<<"S)"<<endl;
        return output;
    }
};
//child class 2
class Vampire : public Player{
public:
    //constructor
    Vampire():Player(){
    }
    static size_t drain;
    void attacks(Player& other)override{
        this->initattacks(other);
        this->Player::hitPoints= this->Player::hitPoints+ drain;
    }
    ostream& print(ostream& output)const override{
        cout<<"Vampire ("<<Player::hitPoints<<"HP, "<<strength <<"S)"<<endl;
        return output;
    }
};

//initializing static variables
//why do i need to do this or else code doesnt work???
size_t Player::baseHitPoints;
size_t Player::baseStrength;
size_t Warrior::bonus;
size_t Vampire::drain;

int main(){
    //save players in a vector. Can be later made into two vectors with two teams
    vector <Player*> arena;
    ifstream input;
    input.open("settings.txt");
    string temp;
    unsigned int x;
    unsigned int y;
    unsigned int z;
    input>>temp;
    input>>x>>y;
    Player::baseHitPoints=x;
    Player::baseStrength=y;
    while (input.peek() != EOF){
        input >> temp;
        if(temp == "Warrior"){
            input>>z;
            Warrior::bonus=z;
            arena.push_back(new Warrior);
            
        }
        if(temp == "Vampire"){
            input>>z;
            Vampire::drain=z;
            arena.push_back(new Vampire);
        }
        
    }
    //fighting loop
    for(unsigned int i =0; i<100;i++){
        arena[i%2]->attacks(*(arena[(i+1)%2]));
        if(((arena[(i+1)%2])->isAlive())==0){
            cout<<"Winner is :"<<endl;
            cout<<*(arena[i%2]);
            cout<<"Looser is :"<<endl;
            cout<<*(arena[(i+1)%2]);
            break;
        }
    }
        if (arena[0]->isAlive() and arena[1]->isAlive()){
            cout<<"No Winner nor looser :"<<endl;
            cout<<*(arena[0]);
            cout<<*(arena[1]);

        }
    input.close();
}
```

Comment: The `virtual` keyword is the blessed method for doing run-time polymorphism. By what metric are you seeking a "better" approach?

Comment: @Botje The Objects im creating are at end of the day Child class objects too. Why cant i access their child methods directly once i save them in a vector of their Parent class

Comment: Please define what you mean by "access directly". Have you learned about the concept of "downcasting" and the concrete `dynamic_cast` keyword yet?

Comment: @botje no i have not. Imma look into them, thanks. By directly i mean like arena[0]->Warrior::attack()

Comment: What if `arena[0]` was actually a Vampire or a Dog instead of a Warrior? That is why you need to downcast.